# Bullet firing backwards in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm creating a game with Unity and I'm learning C#. I needed some help with a bullet firing mechanism for my game so I found the below script on Unity Answers. It works great, but fires the bullet backwards (which would land anyone in the game in a bad situation). Could anyone help? Thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShootDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody projectile;
    public float speed = 20;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
        {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Rigidbody instantiatedProjectile = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, 
transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            instantiatedProjectile.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0, speed));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have would work if you had the forward (blue axis) of the gameobject  of `ShootDemo` pointing in the direction you'd want to shoot.

[image: example of axes]

The fact that does that shoots it in the opposite direction means the forward is pointing is actually pointing in the opposite direction.

Taking that into account by negating speed will reverse the velocity to create the desired effect:

```
instantiatedProjectile.velocity = transform.forward * -speed;
```

Or in the format you've already used

```
instantiatedProjectile.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0, -speed));
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using the method in which the script is applied to the gun, and the bullet is applied to the script. Would that work? I do not have a GameObject called ShootDemo; that is the name of the script.

(By the way, I appreciate your effort in explaining what the blue arrow is, but I already know it's the z axis. Thanks, though!)

Comment: Oh, OK. Huzzah! It works! Anyways, thanks, and if it hadn't come through I'll mark your answer as legit.